# Function and for loop in R not assigning/resetting vectors in global environment

Tags: r

I have written a function `fun` that calculates true positive rates `aaa` and false positive rates `bbb` for different data sets. The problem is that although I have defined these values outside of the function in the global environment, they are not getting updated nor are the values being reset with different data sets. Here is my function:

```
##Define in global environment
N <- 0
P <- 0
threshold <- seq(1,20, by=2)
aaa <- bbb <- 0
X=Y=0

fun <- function(dat){
threshold <- seq(1,20,by=2)
P = 0
N = 0
P <- sum(dat$V1==1)  #True positive cases
N <- sum(dat$V1==0) #True negative cases
aaa <- bbb <- 0
for(i in 1:length(threshold)){ ##Do this for every threshold
  X=Y=0
  for(j in 1:nrow(dat)) {  ##Evaluate every row
     if(dat$V2[j] > threshold[i]) {  ##Test variable
      if(dat$V3[j]==1){X = X+1} ##(true positive)
     else{Y=Y+1}  ##Else Y + 1 (false positive)
  }
}
aaa[i]= X/P
bbb[i] = Y/N
}}
```

I would like to access these vectors `aaa` and `bbb` outside of this function to analyze them. I would also like the values of P, N, etc to reset for every different evaluation of the function, but this is not happening. Should I not define these values outside the function first?

Thanks!

Comment: your `for` loops do not look very r-ish ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<<-` for updating outside the function scope

Comment: and avoid using `=` for assignment or updates. The only place where it should be used is for giving its attributes to a function.

Comment: and more generally, I don't see why you want to update a variable outside a function instead of just producing an output... why don't you `return(list(aaa, bbb, X, Y, N, P))` at the end of your function?

Comment: thank you so much! returning a list is definitely a much more efficient way to code this.